# discord RPC error when i try to run the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord-rpc

when i try to run the code i get this error. i wrote this code with the help of a tutorial in youtube but i don't know what is the mistake i made in this.

`Error: Could not connect at Socket.onerror (/home/runner/Toshiro/node_modules/discord-rpc/src/transports/ipc.js:32:16) at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26) at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28) at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12) at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8) at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)`

my code:

```js
const clientId = "960430276532645888"
const DiscordRPC = require("discord-rpc");
const RPC = new DiscordRPC.Client({ transport: "ipc" });

DiscordRPC.register(clientId);

async function setActivity() {
  if (!RPC) return;
  RPC.setActivity({
    details: `Reading`,
    state: `all subjects`,
    startTimestamp: Date.now(),
    largeImageKey: `books`,
    largeImageText: `books`,
    smallImageKey: `verified`,
    smallImageText: `verified`,
    instance: false,
    buttons: [
      {
        label: `Join Me :)`,
        url: `https://www.sanfransentinel.com/combine-study.html`,

      },
    ]
  });
};

RPC.on('ready', async () => {
  setActivity();

  setInterval(() => {
    setActivity();
  }, 15 * 1000);
})

RPC.login({ clientId }).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Take a read through here: https://github.com/iCrawl/discord-vscode/issues/85.

It looks like it may just be the permissions on your computer.

Try running the code editor as admin and make sure Discord isn't running admin. [How to run an application as admin.](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-run-app-administrator-windows-10)

**If you are not running it locally it wont work**, the library connects to your local running discord client. If you host it on a different machine it cannot connect anymore.